# Meaning of Trust in "Trust extends TaxPayer"

Tags: word-meaning

I know the meaning of the verb trust, but in this case I am not sure about the meaning of the noun `Trust` in the following Java source code:

```
class Trust extends TaxPayer {
    private boolean nonProfit;

    public Trust(long inc, boolean nonProf) {
        super(inc);
        nonProfit = nonProf;
    }

    public boolean isNonProfit() {
        return nonProfit;
    }
}
```

I decided to ask the question here because my question is related to the meaning of a word and not a programming issue.

So, according to the code, a trust is supposed to be profit or nonprofit and pays taxes, but what exactly is it?

Comment: [Trust](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trust), definition 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the meaning of a variable name. Variable names refer to arbitrary programming entities, not to real-world entities, and the names themselves have no necessary or predictable connection with English-language words of the same form.

Comment: In this case, "Trust" means "Company"

Comment: @StoneyB: While that's often true, in this case it seems entirely reasonable that the name *does* refer quite directly to an obvious legal concept by that exact name.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Quite true; but the 'meaning' of *Trust* in the program may have only a very tenuous connection with the actual meaning in the real world, depending on what aspects of real-world *trusts* the program needs to model. In this case, for instance, the program seems to be concerned only with the *trust*'s tax status.

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a class representing a type of real world entity. The OP is trying to understand the meaning of the word in the context of tax paying entities, so that he/she can better interpret the code.

Answer (score 1):

At least in American law, it's a legal entity that exists to own and manage something of value for certain people to benefit from (*beneficiaries*). For example, it is possible to set up a trust to manage an inheritance so that someone who is currently a child or teenager can later have money for college, without relying on the financial abilities of the child to make good investments and avoid spending on foolish things. The basic idea is that the *trustees*, who decide how to spend or invest the money, are *trusted* to make good decisions on behalf of someone else.